# ASP MVC5 Method not hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a method in my EventsController with the following definition:

```
public JsonResult Index(string id)
{
    ...
}
```

When I try to get to it from the browser using http://localhost:57715/events/some_string , I cannot reach it. But when I browse to http://localhost:57715/events instead, my debug point gets hit and id is null. Why is that? My route definition is as follows (I haven't changed it):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you request `http://localhost:57715/events/some_string`, The MVC framework does not know `some_string` is an action method name or the **id** param value. So you should explicitly specify the parameter name.

This should work

`http://localhost:57715/events?id=some_string`

**OR** you can use the url which has both controller name and action method name along with your id param value

`http://localhost:57715/events/yourActionMethodName/some_string`

If you aboslutely want the url `yourSite/events/some_string` to work, You may consider enabling attribute routing and specify a route pattern like above on your action method like below

```
public class EventsController : Controller
{
    [Route("Events/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return Content("id : "+id);
    }
}
```

Now the request `yourSite/events/some_string` will work will be handled by your index action method of EventsController.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, was a simple thing. Instead of going using `http://localhost:57715/events/some_string` I should be using `http://localhost:57715/events/Index/some_string`